# JVM optimisation of zero-length arrays

Tags: java, arrays

As all zero-length arrays of a particular type are identical, does the JVM optimise allocation of zero-length arrays to use one shared instance for all such allocations?

Comment: Random -1 without an explanation helps nobody.

Comment: @LeeMeador It seems to be (?) someone gets upset that OP answered hims/herself.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Reasonable sir. Still worth a reason.

Comment: The question submission form has a feature for easilly answering your own question, so the SO creators *want* OPs to answer their own questions.

Comment: Not me; I upvoted the question, if you include a reference for the source I'll upvote the answer too. The -1 is wrong, IMO.

Comment: "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. And it may not do so, because each created zero-length array object could be used as a different synchronization monitor. [Quoth Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Synchronization is built around an internal entity known as the intrinsic lock or monitor lock...
>   Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it.

For example, in the following code, different threads could call `x.methodA()` and `x.methodB()` without blocking.

```
 private final int[] a;
 private final int[] b;

 Ctor(int n) {
    a = new int[n];
    b = new int[n];
 }

 public final methodA() {
    synchronized(a) {
       ...
    }
 }

 public final methodB() {
    synchronized(b) {
       ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Any official sources saying so?

Comment: This answer is correct. All objects in Java are mutable due to the lock. It's quite a fundamental thing about Java and well known. Also new objects need to compare different with `==`. It's a pity Java doesn't have good support for value objects, but there you go.

Comment: It seems to be right, but is this the one reason for the question?

Comment: Yes, all arrays have their own monitor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860462/synchronizing-on-an-array-does-it-synchronize-on-all-the-elements-or-on-the-arr

Comment: Unlike primitive wrappers, Strings etc. java arrays are mutable.  If sharing empty arrays were allowed the run time would have to have extra housekeeping for stuff like copy-on-write and so on.

Comment: This is a great, simple answer. I hadn't considered object monitors. The issue of mutability is not relevant: a zero-length array is technically immutable, just like a String object is technically immutable. Both can be used as object monitors for locks. Also, @EvgeniyDorofeev's answer that *`new` always creates a new object* should not be surprising at all.

Answer (score 1):

`new` always creates a new object. Empty arrays are immutable and it is possible to use a cached instance instead for optimization. But this is the programmer duty to implement this optimization.

Comment: Can you please post a reference to the JLS for this? I'm sure  it is true, but having the reference would be nice.