# Does a modern JVM optimize read only collection allocations

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

I was a little curious about the following optimization possibility but not sure how to verify this myself, maybe somebody already knows the answers.

We have a lot of similar code like this in our application. Basically it is a statefull handler (saga) that is started by some message (`MyStartingMessage`) and can later by continued by some other message (`MyCotinueMessage`). Because there are multiple instances of those `StatefullHandler`'s we want to check if the Continue message should be handled by a given instance. Therefor we set some state in the handler and when a message is received we check every handler instance if the state in the message matches the handler state, only then the message is handled by this handler instance.

In the example shown below some framework will extract the matchers and check if any of those matches the received continue message instance.

Because we handled thousands of such messages per second I was curious if the JVM does optimize the instance allocations (after some time) to not create a new instance every time.

```
    class StatefullHandler implements MessageHandler {

    public void handle(final MyStartingMessage m) {
        m.setState(m.getUserId()); // used by the matchers
    }

    public void handle(final MyContinueMessage m) {
        // handle
    }

    // only returned for queries and never modified
    public Collection<MessageMatcher> matchers() {
        // message will only be handled by this instance if state matches
        // is this new operator optimized 'away' after some time??
        return ImmutableSet.of(MessageMatcher.for(MyContinueMessage.class, msg -> msg.getUserId())); 
    }
}
```

Without the optimization I would effectivly need to write this:

```
class StatefullHandler implements MessageHandler {

    private static final MATCHERS = ImmutableSet.of(
        MessageMatcher.for(MyContinueMessage.class, msg -> msg.getUserId())); 

        public void handle(final MyStartingMessage m) {
            m.setState(m.getUserId()); // used by the matchers
        }

        public void handle(final MyContinueMessage m) {
            // handle
        }

        public Collection<MessageMatcher> matchers() {
            return MATCHERS;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Distantly related to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027761/jvm-optimisation-of-zero-length-arrays

Comment: In Java 8, it is highly likely the JVM will optimise away the object allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM cannot reuse an old object instance if you explicitly used the `new` keyword, because this would violate the Java Language Specification. First, when you create objects `A` and `B` via `new` it's guaranteed that `A == B` will return `false`. Second, it's guaranteed that you can synchronize on `A` and `B` independently without waiting for each other. Were JVM reuse old objects, this would not be guaranteed. Thus JVM cannot reuse them even for the simplest cases like `new Integer(1)`.

In some cases you can rely on caching performed by third-party libraries, but in your particular case Guava's `ImmutableSet.of` reuses the existing object only for empty set. So in your case having `static` field seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Well, it could, if it can prove that you never use `A == B` or any other identity based operation. But you cannot prove whether it does from within the Java code…

Answer (score 1):

While the JVM cannot reuse an object it can avoid creating it in the first place.

If after inlining (i.e. looking at your caller, and it's caller etc), your object lives and dies in the same method it can be placed on the stack and possibly eliminated using Escape Analysis.

In your case, it is entirely possible that not object the `of()` but the lambda object are also eliminated and this doesn't create any objects.  This depends entirely on your use case and whether the optimiser can eliminate the object creation.

I suggest you use a commercial profiler or Flight Recorder to check if objects are actually created or not.